# Symfony2 Twig Iterator

Tags: php, symfony

I have form $form, which have text field for each entity **User**.

```
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder();
    $form->add('users', 'collection');
    foreach ($query->getResult() as $user)
    {            
        $form->get('users')->add($user->getName(), 'text', array('data' => $user->getName()));
    }
```

I need to access specific input form by its ID number. So i have to be able to do something like this:

```
{{ form_widget(form.users[0]) }}
```

But it doesn't work. I can't use this:

```
{% for user in form.users %}
```

I need to access text fields specificly by their id's

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution.

```
{% set interator = form.users.iterator %}
{{ interator.seek(0) }}
{{ form_widget(interator.current) }}
```